# Is it possible to detect media device is remove during in between a webrtc voip call

Tags: webrtc

Hi is it possible to detect that a media device say headphone is removed during a ongoing webrtc call.We need this so that peer can re negotiate again.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you will get an error if you're using that media device. If not then you should poll on `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`.